# How can Yum tell me the version of depencencies?

Tags: linux, dependencies, rpm, yum

I've installed a package with Yum (Varnish 3.0.2).  However, a feature I need has been removed so I need to roll back.

According to the documentation, the feature was removed in 3.0-Beta, so I wanted to revert to the latest version prior to that.  (This is 2.1.5)

This is installed now, but there were three RPMs to install for it (from http://users.linpro.no/ingvar/varnish/2.1.5/2.1.5-1/el5/x86_64/).

After some *faffing* about with missing dependencies these got installed.  However, the feature I need is still not there.  I'm wondering if one of the dependencies is actually from a newer build.

*Do you know how I can see the versions of all the dependencies of a Yum installed package?*

Comment: yum deplist <your-pacakge-name> does not work?

Comment: @hovanessyan

Thanks, this doesn't show the version numbers though, only filenames.

Answer (score 1):

@hovanessian is right. You won't get any more than what deplist shows.

There are few kinds of dependencies in spec file:

- file dependencies

  > dependency: /usr/bin/env
  >    provider: coreutils.x86_64 8.4-16.el6

  There is no version as the file may be provided by multiple packages
- virtual dependencies

  > dependency: python(abi) = 2.6
  >    provider: python.x86_64 2.6.6-29.el6

  The package "provides" some features, other packages can depend on. For example python package provides versioned python(abi).
- package dependencies

  > dependency: python-twisted-core >= 8.2.0
  >    provider: python-twisted-core.x86_64 8.2.0-4.el6
  >    provider: python-twisted-core.i686 8.2.0-4.el6

Virtual and package dependencies may be versioned and if there is no exact version listed you may try earlier/later version but results are not always satisfactory.

More on dependencies: http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/Dependencies